# TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am running some automation tests on Windows using Ruby and IEDriverServer.exe. When I run the `rake users_creation` command I get this error and I don't know what it means:

```
C:\Users\SolaresIntern\Desktop\Developer\Quality-Assurance>rake users_creation
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber --require features features/users
_creation/*.feature --profile html_report
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
C:/Users/SolaresIntern/Desktop/Developer/Quality-Assurance/Rakefile:25:in `block
 (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => users_creation
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This led me into looking at the Rakefile and this is what's in there:

```
require 'cucumber/rake/task' require 'resque/tasks' require 'resque'

require_relative 'lib/queue/start_script'

SPEC_SUITES = [
  { id: 'everything', title: 'All the testcases', features: "features/**/*.feature", done: false },
  { id: 'class_creation', title: 'Teacher adds a class', features: "features/class_managing/*.feature", done: false },
  { id: 'users_creation', title: 'Sign up students and teachers', features: "features/users_creation/*.feature", done: false },
  { id: 'join_a_class', title: 'Student joins a class', features: "features/students_dashboard/join_a_class.feature", done: false },
  { id: 'create_assignment', title: 'Create an assignment', features: "features/lessons_assignments/*.feature", done: false},
  { id: 'join_class_with_assignment', title: 'Student joins a class with assignments', features: "features/students_dashboard/join_a_class_with_assignments.feature", done: false}
]

SPEC_SUITES.each do |suite|
  desc "Ejecuta todos los specs en la suite #{suite[:title]}"
# task "#{suite[:id]}", [:entorno, :browser] do |t, args|
  task "#{suite[:id]}" do |t|
#   args.with_defaults(:entorno => ENV['ENTORNO'], :browser => ENV['BROWSER'])
#   ENV['ENTORNO']=args.entorno.downcase
#   ENV['BROWSER']=args.browser
    Rake::Task["#{suite[:id]}:run"].execute
  end

  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new("#{suite[:id]}:run") do |t|
    t.cucumber_opts = "--require features #{suite[:features]} --profile html_report #{ENV['CUKES_OPT']}"
  end
end

desc "Enqueue a Test"

task :enqueue, [:entorno, :browser, :test, :cukes_opt] do |t, args|
  params = Hash.new
  params[:cukes_opt]=args.cukes_opt
  params[:entorno]=args.entorno
  params[:browser]=args.browser
  params[:test]=args.test
# Resque.redis = '10.254.21.185:6379'
  Resque.enqueue(StartScript,params)
end
```

Everything runs smoothly on OSX Yosemite. I only have this problem on Windows.

Comment: In which line are you facing the error...

Comment: the error is a generic one indicating that you are attempting to use a nil. in your case going to guess that you need to set the CUKES_OPT environment variable to successfully run it.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna On lines 4 and on. I am using CMD w/ Ruby to run the command. (I am also new and don't know much of coding.)

Comment: @Mircea how would I do that? I know I would go to system properties>advanced>Environmental Variables.. but I am lost after that.

Comment: Which one is line 25 in that rake file...

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Yes, all of the second code is from the Rake file

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Line numbers changed because of my edit. Line 25 is the first `end`.

Comment: try running rake with `rake users_creation CUKES_OPT=<required value>`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna answered how to pass in CUKES_OPT :)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna what would I put as a required value? 1?

Comment: I'm not sure about that...I don't know what that variable takes. You should be knowing that. Find out if it is an integer or string. Say if CUKES_OPT should be like 1,2,3 then the command should be `rake users_creation CUKES_OPT=1` or if CUKES_OPT should be like 'one', 'test', 'user' then the command should be `rake users_creation CUKES_OPT='test'` Thats all I can say.

Comment: Or you can do one thing as you said it runs on Yosmite OSX. You can add a print line before `Cucumber::Rake::Task.new("#{suite[:id]}:run")` like   `puts ENV['CUKES_OPT']` run it in Yosmite and get the value and set it.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna sorry I am really new to this. So I added the 'puts ENV[CUKES_OPT']' line right before the one you mentioned. Now to get the value would I run the same 'rake users_creation' command on Yosemite?

Comment: Yes. check whats getting printed. Just run using the same command how you used to run in Yosmite previously.

Comment: I will continue to work around with it. I will post some results when I get the chance to.